# T-SQL How to get the first item in the last CODE group

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Example:

```
   ID       CODE    DOS
1. 58225111 2730    5/1/2013
2. 58225111 2730    6/1/2013
3. 58225111 2730    7/1/2013
4. 58225111 1930    8/1/2013
5. 58225111 2730    9/1/2013
6. 58225111 2730    10/1/2013
7. 58225111 2730    11/1/2013
8. 58225111 2730    12/1/2013
```

Basically, I want to query the row number 5, the most current CODE with its Min DOS if that makes sense

I've been scratching my head on this problem and I hope someone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What makes that row special? You really need to describe your problem a lot better. The title should reflect the problem you have and not be this generic.

Comment: What conditions you applied to select those rows?

Comment: How can you identify the row? Is it always the nth ordered by a specific column and direction? Is one of the fields in the row a fixed value?

Comment: What do you mean "most current code with min dos"? the row you labeled 6, or the actual 6th row, neither of which meet those criteria and yet it was pointed out

Comment: A better title would have been something like _How to get the first item in the last group_

Comment: How does row 5 meet your criteria when 1-3 have the same code but lesser DOSes?  Shouldn't row 1 be the returned row?

Comment: @Kritner I think it's because it's the first row in the last contiguous group of rows sharing code with the last row. At least that's my interpretation.

Comment: @jpw if that is the case then it's understandable why OP is scratching his head.  The order in which data in inserted into tables shouldn't matter, it could/should have a FK relationship to another table keeping track of contiguous groups perhaps.  What is the key on this table?  how are you ordering your data to get the rows in this order every time?  Won't throwing indeces on the table change the default ordering of data?

Comment: @Kritner Agree. I think it might be the date that determines order.

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you want, despite the question being pretty unclear.

You want the first row with the last code, so in your sample data, it's the 5th row: `58225111 2730    9/1/2013` as it's the first row in the last group of rows with the same code.

If I misunderstood your intent please clarify.

This query should (probably) give you the correct result. I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish the same thing though, but this was what came first to me.

```
;WITH AllRows (id, code, dos, r) 
AS 
(
    SELECT id, code, dos, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id ASC) AS r 
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT * FROM AllRows 
WHERE r = (
    SELECT MAX(r)+1 
    FROM AllRows 
    WHERE 
      id != (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM YourTable ORDER BY dos DESC) 
      OR
      code != (SELECT TOP 1 code FROM YourTable ORDER BY dos DESC) 
)
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0041a/2)

Comment: Sorry everyone for all the confusion, and thanks jpw for reading my mind. The query you provided doesn't work when there are more than one ID in the table.

Comment: Could you provide an example of data that makes it fail and what the expected output should be. It's might be a minor fixable error in the query.

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0041a/1

Although I have read many posts, this is my first time posting. I will look for some guide on how to post correctly...

Comment: @Jake Without any key to guarantee order the result will not be deterministic if you have several id with the same date. With the new sample data the last code is 2730, but it's impossible to determine from which id.